# How to open migration assistant on an ipad

Tags: ipad

How do I open migration assistant on an iPad-2?

I have tried in settings but can not find it.

Comment: there is no way to "migrate" on an iPad 2 as it is a software designed for mac. To do this, you have to back up the iPad to iCloud or to a computer, then put the backup onto the new iPad.

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the old iPad, make a backup via iTunes or iCloud, reset the new iPad if you have already activated it as a new iPad, and when asked, select the "Restore from backup" option.
Full instructions here: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12521